# Android - TabLayout in AndroidX

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I just tried to implement tabLayout on Android with androidX and im not able to do it.

Is tabLayout on androidX deprecated?

Comment: You can use the [**`TabLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TabLayout.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add **material library** as a dependency to **`build.gradle`** file to use `TabLayout`

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```

also inclue `google()` maven repository to the `repositories` section of the root **`build.gradle`**

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
    }
}
```

> You can read the [Getting started with Material Components for
>   Android](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/) to learn more about the library.

Answer (score 1):

[TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout) belongs to Maven artifact com.android.support:design:$version

if you want to use TabLayout in androidX you need to add **material library**

Ref : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Ref : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings

so you need to add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` in dependency.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
}
```